# Pandas Series with column names for each value above a minimum

Tags: python, pandas

I try to get a new series from a DataFrame. This series should contain the column names of the DataFrame's values that are above some value for each row of the DataFrame. But beginning from the left of the DataFrame, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))

>>> df

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   2   4   6   8   8   4
1   2   0   9   7   7   1
2   1   7   7   7   3   0
3   5   4   4   0   1   7
4   9   6   1   5   1   5


min = 3
```

Expected Output:

```
0    B
1    C
2    B
3    A
4    A
dtype: object
```

Here the output's row 0 is "B" because in the DataFrame row index 0 column "B" is the most left column that has a value that is equal or bigger than `min = 3`.

I know that I an use `df.idxmin(axis = 1)` to get the column names of the minimum for each row but I have now clue at all how to tackle this more complex problem.

Thanks for help or hints!

Comment: could you please revise your expected output? For the `row=0` it should be `B` (9>=3 and is the most left one which is `>=3`), for `row=1` -> `A`, `row=2` -> `A`???

Comment: Oh, something went wrong. You are right of course, I have edited both, the dataframe and the expected output. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE - index of the first element in each row, satisfying condition:**

more elegant and more efficient version from @DSM:

```
In [156]: (df>=3).idxmax(1)
Out[156]:
0    B
1    C
2    B
3    A
4    A
dtype: object
```

my version:

```
In [149]: df[df>=3].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index(), axis=1)
Out[149]:
0    B
1    C
2    B
3    A
4    A
dtype: object
```

**Old answer - index of the minimum element for each row:**

```
In [27]: df[df>=3].idxmin(1)
Out[27]:
0    E
1    A
2    C
3    C
4    F
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives each row's minimum, for all values >=3 as far as I see. It doesn't look from the left to take the value from the most left column that is >=3, right?

Comment: Can't we just do `(df >= 3).idxmax(axis=1)`?  (Note that I accidentally typed `min` instead of `max` the first time I wrote this.)

Comment: "first_valid_index", wow, did not know that. Works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: @smiss, please pay attention at the updated answer - the version from DSM is more elegant and more efficient/fast!

Comment: Yes works very fast. Just tried both solutions on a much bigger df and had 1.73s per loop vs. 136 ms. Thank you both.